# função for no Python3 - como fazer um print de todos os elementos de uma series

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

```
i = 0
for item in test['text'][i]:
    print(test['text'][i])
    print(i)
    i+=1
```

no meu dataset "test" eu tenho 3262 itens( é uma series ) , entretanto quando eu faço o "for" ele "printa" apenas 32 itens

Answer (score -1, accepted):

seja bem vindo na comunidade.
já tentou fazer o seguinte?

```
for i in range(1,32): # percorre um laço de 1 até 32 
     print('Numero: '+str(i)+' Dicionario: '+str(test['text'][i])) # mostra o numero percorrido e mostra o dicionario + o texto equivalente ao numero
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você está fazendo com este código é na realidade, iterando os elementos dentro da variável `test['text'][i]`.

Talvez você esteja na realidade, tentando iterar sobre o elemento `test['text']`.

Execute o seguinte código:

```
for item in test['text']:
    print(item)

print("Quantidade de itens no dicionário test, usando a chave text: ", len(test['text']) )
```